# What type of nut is this and how do I put it back into the chipboard?

Tags: repair, wood, hole-repair

Here are the images. Some time ago this nut (by accident) burst out of the wood. Now I don't know how to put it back. Do I buy a new one or do I use this and how do I fill the broken wood i.e epoxy or wood filler of some sort?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is futile to try to reattach in the same location, whatever was held by that nut. The particle board is forever compromised at that spot, whether you fill it for appearance purposes or not. Find a different way to attach whatever was there (e.g., screws, nails, glue, or combination of those things).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hard to be sure from pics that show more details of fingers than nut, but it looks like basically a threaded nut insert, which come in a wide variety.  Seeing as you've torn yours out of your particle board, it's not going back in.  You *might* have some luck filling the hole with epoxy and drilling a new hole for the threaded nut, but you might need to do some prep work on the hole first.

Comment: Not adding an answer as this seems right to me; my only suggestion would be, that instead of filling the hold completely, to super glue/CA the piece into place at the bottom and then use epoxy in two pours with the first going up to the hex part, wait for it to cure, and then the second up to flush with the top of bolt or wood (whichever is lower).

Comment: @UnhandledExcepSean - that would, of course, fill the insert with epoxy too… not great.

Comment: @Tetsujin I suppose that all depends on how far the screw threads into it. If the screw isn't full depth, it wouldn't be an issue. But you could also thread the screw into it with a release agent (thin wax coating on the screw) when doing the pour(s).

Comment: Bear in mind that chip/particle board is made by compressing flakes of wood together with a bonding agent under high pressure and temperature to set. Repair this kind of wood is often a bit of a futile exercise. Epoxy _might_ hold, but it might not. You may end up with the threaded insert, encased in epoxy, with some more chips of wood falling out since the original construction has been compromised. Then again, it may last another 10 years...

Comment: I have put in epoxy, will wait for 1h before I put in the next dose. Right new it only fills the cavity in which that metal thing is going to rest.

Comment: If this fails then I could get in an expert to make a new hole and insert the threaded thing.

Comment: @quantum231 Or you could remove the insert and  the screw, fill it with wood putty, drill it out, and put in a wood glued dowel. If it were mine, I probably would have just filled both parts after removing hardware, drilled a pilot hole from the other side of the blowout, and screwed them together. Many easy fixes that can be effective to this issue.

Comment: If only we had some more context of the function of the insert—what does it fasten to the torn up particleboard piece?—we might be able to suggest better solutions than simply trying to glue it back in.

Comment: OK, this is a L shaped office desk used in work from home setup. The damage has happened to the top part of the desk.

Comment: I had put in some epoxy, it has dried. Lets see how well its works when I assemble everything together. What is this thing called wood putty? Can it be used with this chipboard material?